# Springboot :BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to execute my springboot application by running the jar created  with maven and getting below exception which is not getting resolved after so many attempts.Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Please find below exception trace.

```
 2016-01-28 11:35:42.034  INFO 3732 --- [           main] Application                              : Starting Application on DFWLW72RTG262 with PID 3732 (C:\project\RestSpringBoot\target\springboot-0.0
.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by vaigupta in C:\project\RestSpringBoot\target)
2016-01-28 11:35:42.123  INFO 3732 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7
d7cd6ad: startup date [Thu Jan 28 11:35:42 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-28 11:35:42.149  WARN 3732 --- [           main] ionWarningsApplicationContextInitializer :

** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.


2016-01-28 11:35:48.607  WARN 3732 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springfra
mework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:177)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
        at Application.main(Application.java:9)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened b
ecause it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:591)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
        ... 18 common frames omitted

2016-01-28 11:35:48.645  INFO 3732 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0
.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.
0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestS
pringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-log
ging-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.j
ar!/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0
.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springbo
ot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/pr
oject/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0
.15.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
lib/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0
.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoo
t/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/p
roject/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, ja
r:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-aop-4.1
.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spr
ing-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0
.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-expression-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/Rest
SpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter
-aop-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.4.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/s
pringboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpri
ngBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/tomcat-juli-8.0.15.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/pro
ject/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jboss-logging-ann
otations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-
SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1
-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-S
NAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/pr
oject/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/javassist
-3.18.1-GA.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-orm-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
!/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/ta
rget/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpring
Boot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-aspects-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/C:/project/RestSpringBoot/target/springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/hsqldb-2.3.2.jar!/]
2016-01-28 11:35:48.669 ERROR 3732 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springfra
mework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:177)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
        at Application.main(Application.java:9)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened b
ecause it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:591)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
        ... 18 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [or
g/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:177)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
        at Application.main(Application.java:9)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened b
ecause it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:591)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
        ... 18 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [or
g/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:177)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
        at Application.main(Application.java:9)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened b
ecause it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:591)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
        ... 18 more
```

below is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBoot</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Example</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


  </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: See this: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened b
ecause it does not exist`

Comment: @ Jens: yes I have seen that not sure why it is coming . I am not having any spring security dependency in my pom.xml file.

Comment: I've found answer on my similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804357/org-springframework-beans-factory-beandefinitionstoreexception-failed-to-parse?noredirect=1#comment80556145_46804357

Answer (score 38):

Your code is in the default package, i.e. you have `.java` files in `src/main/java` with no `package` statement at the top. There's a warning message in the log indicating that this is likely to cause problems:

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.
```

You need to move your code into a package of its own. For example, move your `.java` files into `src/main/java/com/example` and add `package com.example;` to the top of each file.

Comment: Thanks It worked, I also changed the main file name as com.example.Application in pom.xml file.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson Could you explain why does that happen ? Well removing the main file from default package to a named one did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks it worked.why should I put it into a package?

Answer (score 23):

Sometime you can run `mvn clean install` in command line or do it by intellij idea to solve this problem.

I think it's beacause the wrong generation of `target` directionary of this maven project.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved the problem by running my application with maven. e.g.:

> mvn springboot:run

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by running below command.

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add corresponding security config file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers

Answer (score 2):

For gradle projects, run `gradle clean build` to fix issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with this solution. I was getting same error with  maven, i detached project from intelij ide then reattached. It solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error(in place of class file, mine was properties file which was present though in resources folder).

Solution : I detached the gradle project from gradle pane window and reattached it. After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I met this very problem just now, and the reason is certain a class, which is in jar file, implements a interface, which is in my local package (So you can figure it out that I decompiled some classes). However, the package for the interface is not match the class declares indeed. So after moved the interface to the correct package, the error missed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case simple mvn clean compile did the trick but i dont know why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to do a combination of the things suggested above:

`mvn clean`
`mvn install`

However, the install identified a problem with one of my modules

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project locations-determining-dto: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]

And the thing that helped me in the end was to right-click on the pom.xml in IntelliJ and choose Maven > Reload Project.

Weird! Writing this here in case it helps me again in the future...

Comment: Indeed, more than six months later, I had the problem again. Thanks to Stackoverflow, a Google search allowed my past self to my present self! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just delete "out" package which is located in the module and build project again

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35156564)