# Spring boot conflicting bean definition exception

Tags: java, maven, servlets, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am trying to implement a simple spring boot application and deploy it directly on its internal server.Here's my application class

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication



public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

        @Override
        public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
            return builder.sources(Application.class);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
}
```

And here is my Controller class

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(path="/api",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String insertData(@RequestBody String rawJsonData,HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException, IOException{
        JSONParser jparser=new JSONParser();
        Object jsonObj=jparser.parse(rawJsonData);
        JSONObject jObject=(JSONObject)jsonObj;

        FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Aayushi.txt"));
        filewriter.write(jObject.toJSONString());
        return rawJsonData;

    }
}
```

And in my pom.xml, I have the following dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>API</groupId>
  <artifactId>API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
         </configuration>
         </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency><!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>Application</start-class>
         <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

After executing the above code as maven build Spring-boot:run, after the server gets started,it throws these errors

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building API 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ API >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ API ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\main\resources
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\main\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ API ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ API ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\test\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ API ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ API <<<
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ API ---

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

    2017-04-16 12:59:44.416  INFO 7892 --- [           main] Application                              : Starting Application on DESKTOP-CAFJH2F with PID 7892 (C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\target\classes started by aayus in C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API)
    2017-04-16 12:59:44.423  INFO 7892 --- [           main] Application                              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2017-04-16 12:59:44.496  INFO 7892 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1dbea10f: startup date [Sun Apr 16 12:59:44 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    2017-04-16 12:59:44.519  WARN 7892 --- [           main] ionWarningsApplicationContextInitializer : 

    ** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.


    2017-04-16 12:59:52.131  WARN 7892 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
    2017-04-16 12:59:52.138 ERROR 7892 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1dbea10f: startup date [Sun Apr 16 12:59:44 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at Application.main(Application.java:20) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]

    2017-04-16 12:59:52.145 ERROR 7892 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at Application.main(Application.java:20) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted

    [WARNING] 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at Application.main(Application.java:20)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
        ... 19 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 11.226 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-16T12:59:52+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 50M/376M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project API: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

There's no annotation as @ComponentScan in my code.Then why are these errors coming?

Edit 1:After segregating the code into packages,I am getting the following errors:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this warning:

`** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.`

This is probably because your Application class is located in the default package, and generally the application fails to start in this case.

So you should create some package (e.g: `com.mypackage`) and place it inside there.

Comment: please efer to the edited question above.Thanks @thecoder

Answer (score 0):

Andy has found the root cause and give solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35080798/2293534)

### Root Cause Analysis:

Your code is in the default package, i.e. you have `.java` files in `src/main/java` with no package statement at the top. There's a warning message in the log indicating that this is likely to cause problems:

> ** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.

### Solution Procedure:

You need to move your code into a package of its own. For example, move your .java files into `src/main/java/com/example` and add `package com.example;` to the top of each file.

### UPDATE#1:

Please replace your Application.java as below and check again

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

//@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

Comment: even after moving it into a package, errors are coming InvocationTargetException and ApplicationContextException @SkyWalker

Comment: @aayushi please add the next exception full log

Comment: please refer to the edited code above! thanks @SkyWalker

Comment: @aayushi Please check the update and replace the code and let me know the result

Comment: even after doing that,the build is failing with the same issues @SkyWalker

Comment: @aayushi is it possible to upload the code in github? If possible, then share please, I will check

Comment: please find the code at the following link https://github.com/aayushis12/SpringBoot  Thanks!! @SkyWalker