# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a good working application (when I start it in an Eclipse IDE),
but when I trying to start it like standalone jar by this way:

java -jar -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=us Soap2Gis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I've got next issue:

```
18-10-2017 13:35:22.604 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.ric.web.Soap2GisApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
```

Full error stack:

```
18-10-2017 13:35:22.590 [main] ERROR o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@65e2dbf3: startup date [Wed Oct 18 13:35:22 NOVT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.ric.web.Soap2GisApplication.main(Soap2GisApplication.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
18-10-2017 13:35:22.604 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.ric.web.Soap2GisApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.ric.web.Soap2GisApplication.main(Soap2GisApplication.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
    at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingJarResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:621)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:475)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:279)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1293)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.getResources(GenericApplicationContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:278)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:287)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

my Soap2GisApplication:

```
package com.ric.web;

import javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory;

import org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl;
import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.ric.bill.Config;
import com.ric.st.impl.TaskController;

import ru.gosuslugi.dom.signature.demo.commands.Command;
import ru.gosuslugi.dom.signature.demo.commands.SignCommand;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Soap2GisApplication {

    public static Command sc;
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.xml.security.resource.config", "resource/tj-msxml.xml");

        try {
            sc = new SignCommand();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String mode = args != null && args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

        if (AuthConfigFactory.getFactory() == null) {
            AuthConfigFactory.setFactory(new AuthConfigFactoryImpl());
        }

        if (applicationContext != null && mode != null && "stop".equals(mode)) {
            System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, new ExitCodeGenerator() {
                @Override
                public int getExitCode() {
                    return 0;
                }
            }));
        } else {
            System.out.println("CHECCCCCCCCCCCCCK 1");
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Soap2GisApplication.class);
            System.out.println("CHECCCCCCCCCCCCCK 2");
            applicationContext = app.run(args);
            System.out.println("CHECCCCCCCCCCCCCK 3");

            TaskController taskContr = applicationContext.getBean(TaskController.class);
            Config config = applicationContext.getBean(Config.class);

            if (config.getAppTp() == 1) {
                taskContr.otherTask();

            } else {

                try {
                    taskContr.searchTask();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 0);
        }

    }
}
```

my AppConfig:

```
package com.ric.web;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsMultiFormatView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.ric.st", "com.ric.bill.dao", "com.ric.bill.mm", "com.ric.bill", "com.ric.st.builder"})
@ImportResource("spring.xml")
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.ric.bill.dao")
public class AppConfig  implements ApplicationContextAware {

    static ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        ctx = context;
    }

    /**
     * Note that this is a static method which expose ApplicationContext
     **/
    public static ApplicationContext getContext(){
          return ctx;
    }

    @Bean
    public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
      JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
      //resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/reports/");
      resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/");
      //resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jrxml");
      resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
      resolver.setViewNames("rep*");
      resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
      resolver.setOrder(0);
      return resolver;
    }  


}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ric.gis</groupId>
    <artifactId>Soap2Gis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cata1</id>
            <name>cata</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

        <start-class>com.ric.web.Soap2GisApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
          <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
          <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- BWC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ric.bill</groupId>
            <artifactId>BWC</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.M6</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.2</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.security.auth.message/javax.security.auth.message-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.security.auth.message-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache2</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-terracotta</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
          <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>trustedJava</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ric.tjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.diffplug.durian/durian -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.diffplug.durian</groupId>
            <artifactId>durian</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.48</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.55</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.signserver.xades4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>xades4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2-signserver4</version>
        </dependency>
 -->

         <dependency>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.xades4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>xades4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
              </configuration>                

              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target> 
                                <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" update="true" compress="store">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="com/ric/web/Bootstrap.class"/>
                                </zip>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>

                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

my Spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.1:1521:xx" />

        <property name="user" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="20" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="5000" /> 
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="billJPAUint" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.ric.bill</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />


</beans>
```

Also I've read this article, from stackoverflow with similar problem, but it doesn't help me:
[Springboot :BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070455/springboot-beandefinitionstoreexception-failed-to-parse-configuration-class)

I really stuck on this issue. Moreover this app (standalone jar) was well-working several days ago...

Comment: Did you by any chance changed the encoding of your project files from `UTF-8` to something else? This error usually appears in such cases.

Comment: something like these zip related errors could happen if some dependency jar file is corrupted in your local repo but cannot say why eclipse works though

Comment: To pleft, You are exactly right! I've change my project back to UTF-8 and it is working now! Please, suggest this answer, I will accept it, thanks A LOT!

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed this issue by changing my java file encoding back to UTF-8 (as said pleft in comments)
(Previously I ocassionaly set it to wrong one)

This solved the problem completely.