# Spring REST Controller Not Starting

Tags: spring, rest

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.ibm.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-api</name>
<description>Spring API DATA</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

SpringBootApiApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ibm.springboot.*")
@EntityScan("com.ibm.springboot.topics.Topic")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ibm.springboot.topics.TopicRepository")
public class SpringBootApiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApiApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Topic.java

```
 @Entity
 public class Topic {

 @Id
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private String description;



 public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
 }
 public String getId() {
    return id;
 }
 public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
 }
 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
 }
 }
```

TopicController.java

```
@RestController
public class TopicController {

@Autowired
TopicService topicService;

@RequestMapping("/topics")
public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){

    return topicService.getAllTopics();
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/topics")
public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic){
    topicService.addTopic(topic);
}
}
```

TopicRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String>{

}
```

TopicService.java

```
@Service
public class TopicService {

@Autowired
TopicRepository topicRepository;

public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){

    List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    topicRepository.findAll().forEach(topics::add);
    return topics;

}

public void addTopic(Topic topic){
//  topics.add(topic);
    topicRepository.save(topic);
 }


 }
```

While I am running the main class , I am getting the following error.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

> Description:
>
> Field topicRepository in com.ibm.springboot.topics.TopicService
>   required a bean of type 'com.ibm.springboot.topics.TopicRepository'
>   that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ibm.springboot.topics.TopicRepository' in your configuration.

I have checked all the related suggestion given here, but nothing clicked.Please help

Comment: If one Repository extends CrudRepository is it essential to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Repository` annotation from your `TopicRepository` interface.
Should be (no annotation over it):

```
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository{

}
```

**EDIT**

Change your:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ibm.springboot.topics.TopicRepository")
```

To:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses= {com.ibm.springboot.topics.TopicRepository.class})
```

Comment: Anyway @Repository there was wrong. It is enough just to extend the `CrudRepository` in your `TopicRepository` interface. You also have to give `basePackageClasses` option in `@EnableJpaRepositories` see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your time. But still it is not working. Showing the following exception.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/social/config/annotation/SocialConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: That's completely different kind of error. Check here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35080798/3635454